# Extreme times observed when subsetting data frame

Tags: r, memory, time

I am observing extreme computation time when subsetting a large dataframe (or data table) repeatedly (~8gb in memory, 2 million rows by 500 columns). For example:

```
set.seed(100)
tmp_df <-
  data.frame(lapply(1:500, function(i) runif(2e6)))
tmp_df_2 <- tmp_df[tmp_ind, ]
tmp_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(tmp_df)), 8000)
```

I benchmark two operations which return the same subset with 8000 rows, namely:

```
tmp_mbm_obj_1 <- microbenchmark(fn = tmp_df[tmp_ind, ], times = 500)
tmp_mbm_obj_2 <- microbenchmark(fn = tmp_df_2[seq_len(nrow(tmp_df_2)), ], times = 500)
```

which returns the following timings in milliseconds:

| expr | min | lq | mean | median | uq | max | neval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tmp_mbm_obj_1 | 69.045 | 77.8912 | 86.92647 | 81.37625 | 88.7259 | 216.2269 | 500 |
| tmp_mbm_obj_2 | 22.8655 | 26.79845 | 33.08057 | 28.666 | 31.0665 | 289.3311 | 500 |

Notice that the maximum value is much greater than the median value; almost an order of magnitude more for the second case.

This effect is even more pronounced when the data frames are set to be data tables, e.g.:

```
setDT(tmp_df)
setDT(tmp_df_2)
tmp_mbm_obj_dt_1 <- microbenchmark(fn = tmp_df[tmp_ind, ], times = 500)
tmp_mbm_obj_dt_2 <- microbenchmark(fn = tmp_df_2[seq_len(nrow(tmp_df_2)), ], times = 500)
```

The mean time is a lot lower for a data table but the blow out in the maximum time is much worse:

| expr | min | lq | mean | median | uq | max | neval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tmp_mbm_obj_dt_1 | 38.1414 | 41.59365 | 50.36068 | 42.6689 | 44.5913 | 847.2804 | 500 |
| tmp_mbm_obj_dt_2 | 25.8743 | 27.56925 | 34.49421 | 27.94945 | 28.7855 | 793.3998 | 500 |

Is there an explanation for this behaviour?

I am running a Xeon E5-1620 v4 CPU. My `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

and from `memuse::Sys.meminfo()`:

```
Totalram:  63.924 GiB 
Freeram:   45.379 GiB
```

Comment: you're best off profiling the code. how empty is the machine you're running this on? what happens when you force data.table to be single-threaded?

Comment: thanks. how should I profile this code?